# Flutter layout overflows when keyboard shows! Can't make it scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Following is my code, from a layout point of view:

```
/// Entry point into the code.
/// Initialise Firebase first
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(StartDateTracker());
  }, FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError);
}

class StartDateTracker extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CP>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => CP(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          routes: {
            // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
            //'/': (context) => DateTracker(),
            // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
            '/afterLogin': (context) => AfterLogin(),...
          },
          home: DateTracker()),
    );
  }
}

class DateTracker extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DateTrackerState createState() => _DateTrackerState();
}

class _DateTrackerState extends State<DateTracker> {
  bool signUp = false;
  late Future<void> _initializeFlutterFireFuture;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeFlutterFireFuture = _initializeFlutterFire();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      ]);
  }


  /// Change the signup flag
  /// from true to false and vice versa
  changeWidget(){
     if (signUp) {
       setState(()=> signUp = false);
      // signUp = false;
       if (kDebugMode) print('SignUp: $signUp');
     } else {
       setState(()=> signUp = true);
     //  signUp = true;
       if (kDebugMode) print('SignUp: $signUp');
     }
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // TODO: When keyboard appears, this line helps not give error
      // But it is not a solution
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: blue,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeFlutterFireFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    );
                  }
                  // Return sign-in or sign-up screen
                  return signUp? SignUp(changeWidget) : SignIn(changeWidget);
                  break;
                default:
                  // Until future builder is done!
                  return const Center(child: Text('Loading...', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)));
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}



class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {

  final void Function() callBack;

  SignUp(this.callBack);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _controllerEmail = new TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _controllerPass = new TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _controllerRepeatPass = new TextEditingController();

  bool busy = false;

  widthCalculator(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return (width/2)+(0.3 * (width/2));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: widthCalculator(context),child: Image.asset('images/icon_launcher.png')),
          Expanded(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Text('Date Tracker', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Create your account', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                        validator: (value)=> RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(_controllerEmail.text) ? null : 'Please enter a valid email',
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        controller: _controllerEmail,
                        showCursor: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                          filled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                        validator: (value)=> _controllerPass.text.length>=6 ? null : 'Minimum 6 characters',
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        showCursor: true,
                        controller: _controllerPass,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          filled: true,
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                        validator: (value)=> _controllerPass.text.length>=6 && _controllerPass.text != _controllerRepeatPass.text? 'Password do not match' : null,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        showCursor: true,
                        controller: _controllerRepeatPass,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Repeat password',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          filled: true,
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    if (kDebugMode) print('Submit pressed - Register user');
                    busyChanger(true);
                    UserCredential? userCredential = await registerUser(_controllerEmail.text, _controllerPass.text, context);
                    busyChanger(false);

                    if (userCredential!=null){
                      if (kDebugMode) print ('Signed-in as: '+userCredential.user!.email!) ;
                      //if (kDebugMode) print ('Signing out now from: ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email}');
                      //FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/afterLogin');
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: busy? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),)): Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: lGreen,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
                  ),
                  width: widthCalculator(context),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),))),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Already have an account?', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: widget.callBack,
                child: Text(' Sign In ', style: TextStyle(color: lGreen)),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function() callBack;

  SignIn(this.callBack);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _controllerEmail = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerPass = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerRepeatPass = new TextEditingController();
  bool busy = false;

  /// Calculate the width of the screen and return
  /// This is used to calculate the image size on top of the screen.
  widthCalculator(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return (width/2)+(0.3 * (width/2));
  }

  busyChanger(bool b){
    setState(() => busy = b);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(width: widthCalculator(context),child: Image.asset('images/icon_launcher.png')),
          Expanded(child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Text('Date Tracker', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),),
                      Text('Sign In to your account', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                        validator: (value)=> RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(_controllerEmail.text) ? null : 'Please enter a valid email',
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        controller: _controllerEmail,
                        showCursor: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          filled: true,
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      TextFormField(
                        // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                        validator: (value)=> _controllerPass.text.length>=6 ? null : 'Minimum 6 characters',
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        showCursor: true,
                        controller: _controllerPass,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0))),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          filled: true,
                          
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: busy? null : () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    if (kDebugMode) print('Submit pressed - Login user');
                    busyChanger(true);
                    UserCredential? userCredential = await loginUser(_controllerEmail.text.trim(), _controllerPass.text.trim());
                    //busyChanger(false);
                    if (userCredential!=null){
                      if (kDebugMode) print ('Signed-in as: '+userCredential.user!.email!);
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/afterLogin');
                    }
                    busyChanger(false);
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: lGreen,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
                    ),
                    width: widthCalculator(context),
                    child: busy? Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator(),):Center(child: Text('Submit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),))),
              ),
            ],
          )),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Don\'t have an account?', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              GestureDetector(
                // This callback changes the state of the signup variable to show
                // Sign-in Screen and vice versa
                onTap: widget.callBack,
                child: Text(' Sign Up ', style: TextStyle(color: lGreen)),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When keyboard comes out, I get overflow error. I tried the following:

1. Added SingleChildScroll view at different positions but I always get Rendering errors. I tried it straight after Scaffold, before SafeArea, also tried encapsulating Signup/Signin screens but no luck. I need help with fixing this please

Answer (score 0):

I have seen SingleChildScrollView doesnt work properly over SafeArea. You should wrap your Center widget in both of the screens with SingleChildScrollView. 
Other way is to return signUp and signIn Screen wrapped under SingleChildScrollView like

```
return signUp? 
   SingleChildScrollView(child:SignUp(changeWidget)): 
   SingleChildScrollView(child:SignIn(changeWidget));
```

Comment: I tried this and this does not work.

Comment: Anyone? It is still an issue left unresolved